# How can I debug HtmlProvider?

Tags: debugging, f#, f#-data

I'm trying to use HtmlProvider but it fails to detect the tables in the html provided to it. Is there a way to debug this, perhaps enable logging on the HtmlProvider, or some other way to figure out what has gone wrong?

Also, there's another HtmlProvider right next to it that works fine, so the issue is specific to this particular html document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab Source at https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data.

Compile yourself.

Link to this DLL/project.

Debug.

(in b4 tomas-petricek ;-)